# Chose two options in multi-value parameter but pass one value

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am new using multi-value parameters so i have a question about this. My dataset is using a procedure and the value that i have to pass in the procedure are handled in the parameter  **Include Period** and it has two options: **Compulsory** and **Post Compulsory**.
If you chose **Post-Compulsory** label the value passed in the SP would be "Showing payments only after the compulsory period" , if you chose **Compulsory** label the value passed in the SP would be "Showing payments during the compulsory period only" and if you chose **both options** the value passed in the SP would be "Showing payments during the compulsory period and after". So i don't know if there is a way to do that. I set the configuration in available values:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9UT5.png
But i don't know if is posible to configure one value for two different labels.

Notes:

- I can't change anything of the SP

If anyone could help me I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a Third Option?

It would be much easier to change your parameter to NOT be multi-value and add a third option with both and the value for showing all.

```
Compulsory and Post Compulsory | "Showing payments during the compulsory period and after"
```

If, for whatever reason, you're not able to do that, you could count the parameter and if two are selected then use the custom value in the Dataset's expression builder.

```
="EXEC MY_SP @PERIOD = '" & 
    IIF(Parameters!PERIOD.Count = 2, "Showing payments during the compulsory period and after", Parameters!PERIOD.VALUE(0)) & "'"
```